# How to get CefSharp to work in VB.Net WinForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, cefsharp

I am trying to create a browser in VB.Net, using WinForms, and I can't get CefSharp to work. I am using the pre-release NuGet package. I am using this code to construct the browser:

```
    Private m_IsInDesignMode As Boolean = True
Public ReadOnly Property IsInDesignMode() As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_IsInDesignMode
    End Get
End Property
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    m_IsInDesignMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode = LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
    Me.browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("http://emposoft.tk")
    Me.browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

End Sub
```

And I have the following files in the debug folder:
[image: Cef File List]

And I have the en_US file in the locales folder.
When I run the application, no errors or warnings come up, it is just a blank form. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new with CefSharp, but an experienced VB.Net programmer.

Comment: Me.Controls.Add(Me.browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing `CefSharp.WinForms.dll` and `icudtl.dat` from the bin directory.

There are some good tips on getting things set up here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CefSharp_binaries

In particular:

- Have you selected either `x86` or `x64` as your Platform Target?  `AnyCPU` doesn't work.
- Have you got all the correct packages?  Compare your `packages.config` against that in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms

---

The answer ended up being that in version 37 of CefSharp (the current stable version), you need an explicit call to `Cef.Initialize()` before creating the browser, otherwise it does not load.  This is fixed in the `v39.0.0-pre03` NuGet.

The solution is either:

- Upgrade to `v39.0.0-pre03` (it actually has a lot of bug fixes): https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/39.0.0-pre03
- Modify `Form1.Designer.vb` and add a call to `Cef.Initialize()` like in the following:

`Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    m_IsInDesignMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode = LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize()
    Me.browser = New CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://emposoft.com")
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.browser)
End Sub`

Comment: Hi @yoshi, I now added both of those files. I do have x86 selected, and the only thing different in packages.config is instead of `targetFramework="net40"`, it's `targetFramework="net45"`. I have added the following code to `form1_load`: `Dim brsettings As New CefSharp.CefSettings
        brsettings.UserAgent = ("MySurf Labs v3.1")
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(brsettings)` and added this to the top: `Private Property browser As ChromiumWebBrowser` And nothing is showing up still. And I have added `Me.Controls.Add(Me.browser)` to the design file.

Comment: 1) Initialize() should be called earlier before the form is constructed (e.g.https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs). 2) Controls.Add should be called immediately after you construct the ChromiumWebBrowser.

Comment: If this still doesn't work, I encourage you to cut out proprietary code from your project and publish it on GitHub temporarily. This will allow others to try to load it and spot the problem.

Comment: Hi @yoshi, I did find another project that implements Chromium in a much easier way, but it is quite out of date.  I want to get back to implementing this into my project. Let me know if you are still available for me to upload to GitHub.

Comment: Sorry it took so long... I had to reinstall Windows... Here is the project: https://github.com/AJDev77/MySurfBeta

Comment: @AJDev no worries.  Thanks to your source code I was able to find the problem and have updated my answer.

Comment: AnyCPU does work, you just have to do a bit of setup to get it to. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  As an FYI, adding a control to your form is far easier via code if you add a panel and then set the me.browser.parent to be that panel vs. doing it that way.  Then you can control where it goes via the IDE to see it and then code it in by setting Dock to fill.  I see many code segments where they use me.controls.add  but just setting the parent to the panel is more direct so controls.add isn't necessary.